# How to handle exceptions with ContinueWith and WhenAll?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, task

I am trying to load multiple files asynchronously and inform UI when ever each file is done loading,

```
_loadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var files = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
LoadedFiles.Clear();

loads = await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(file =>
{
    var load = LoadAsync(file);
    load.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsCompleted) LoadedFiles.Add(file.Path);
        if (t.IsFaulted) NotifyUser(t.Exception.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        if (t.IsCanceled) NotifyUser("operation was canceled.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
    }, scheduler);
    return load;
}));

private Task<Foo> LoadAsync(StorageFile file)
{
    // exception may be thrown inside load
    return Load(file, _loadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
```

The problem Is when exception is thrown, it is not handled. I know why, because `ContinueWith` creates a new task but im returning the old task.

This is because `ContinueWith` is a void task. but I dont know how to return the result correctly. Im not sure if its safe to use `t.Result` because it may block the UI thread?

---

PS, I've tried this code but I get `a task was cancelled exception` and app crashes even though I'm not cancelling any tasks. only a few exceptions are thrown for loading some files.

```
load = (await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(file =>
{
    var load = LoadAsync(file);
    load.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted) NotifyUser(t.Exception.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        if (t.IsCanceled) NotifyUser("operation was canceled.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
    }, _loadCancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion, scheduler);
    return load.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        LoadedFiles.Add(file.Path);
        return (file, t.Result);
    }, _loadCancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, scheduler); ;
})));
```

Comment: `IsCompleted` will be `true` even if `IsFaulted` or `IsCancelled` are `true`. While `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` will be true only when `IsFaulted` and `IsCancelled` are false. You could add some conditions to `ContinueWith` handling different [TaskContinuationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jimi I was able to solve this problem by looking at Task status.

```
loads = (await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(file =>
{
    return LoadAsync(file).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted) NotifyUser(t.Exception.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        if (t.IsCanceled) NotifyUser("operation was canceled.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);

        if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            LoadedFiles.Add(file.Path);
            return t.Result;
        }

        return null;
    }, scheduler);
}))).Where(x => x != null).ToArray();
```